# pandas: How to merge two dataframes on common values on one or more columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[2,4,6]})
>>> df1
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  6
```

and:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,2,2,3,3, 4],"B":[2,3,4,5,6,7, 8], "C":[11,12,13,14,15,16, 17]})
>>> df2
   A  B   C
0  1  2  11
1  1  3  12
2  2  4  13
3  2  5  14
4  3  6  15
5  3  7  16
6  4  8  17
```

I expect to combine them and have the following where I have complete values of `df2` for common rows on `A`:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  2  11
1  1  3  12
2  2  4  13
3  2  5  14
4  3  6  15
5  3  7  16
```

what I tried:

```
>>> df2.merge(df1, how='outer')
   A  B   C
0  1  2  11
1  1  3  12
2  2  4  13
3  2  5  14
4  3  6  15
5  3  7  16
6  4  8  17
```

Maybe I don't want merge,two dataframes are identical on columns, but one have more rows and more targets for some keys (keys are in A, and targets are B), I want all targets for keys on df1... I tried varies on and how options, none of them were my answer, unless you point it. Otherwise, the other question isn't helpful here

Comment: what do you mean by *common rows*? `A,B = 3,7` does not occur in `df1`. It looks like your expected is `df2[df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]`.

Comment: Maybe you want `df2[df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I editted I meant common rows on A

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh yes, I want that, does it works for multiple columns too?

Comment: @Ahmad *common* means merging with `how='inner'`, not `how='outer'`. And you should pass the merge key as well (and yes, `merge` works for multiple columns, no, `isin` does not)

Comment: @QuangHoang I want rows on df2 but limited to keys on df1

Comment: Yes, that means `inner` merge. Please read the dup link.

Comment: @QuangHoang Maybe I don't want merge, I guess @Ynjx point works.... Two dataframe are identical on columns, but one have more rows and more targets for some keys (key is A, and targets are B), I want all targets for keys on A... I tried varies `on` and `how` options, none of them were my answer, unless you point it. Otherwise, the other question isn't helpful here

Comment: That's what I said initially, and you ask for multiple columns??? `df2.merge(df1[['A']], on=['A'], how='inner'])` is effectively the same with `isin` approach, but `isin` **does not** generalize to multiple column (keys).

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, if df1 also has distinct columns like `D` how can I keep both `C` (from df2) and `D` from df1?

Comment: `df2.merge(df1[['A','D']], on=['A'], how='inner')`.